# Adding support for gb2312 and shift-jis to newlib iconv

Tags: iconv, newlib, shift-jis, gb2312

I have a requirement to convert UCS2 to following code pages

1. ```
     Chinese: gb2312
   ```
2. ```
     Japanese: shift_jis
   ```
3. ```
     Russian : cp1251
   ```
4. ```
     Hungrian, Polish and Cesky: cp1252
   ```
5. ```
     Default: cp1250
   ```

I could see that items 3-5 are supported in newlib iconv library.

For gb2312  or gbk  I could see that it's supported in Cygwin-windows only. Is there a feasibility issue to support gb2312 for embedded cortex M controllers?

I can see Jis implementation in newlib and but is not available for Cygwin.Is It available for embedded   cortex M controllers?

What is the difference between jis and shift-jis, is it compatible with euc_jp

I have tried cp1250,cp1251 and cp1252 successfully but not able to figure out a path for gb2312 and shift_jis

Answer (score 0):

I have partially able to do  for shift_jis by creating tables  using

> ```
>  1. wget ftp://sourceware.org/pub/newlib/newlib-4.2.0.20211231.tar.gz
>  2. tar -xvf newlib-4.2.0.20211231.tar.gz
>  3. cd newlib/libc/iconv/ccs/
>
>  4. wget https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT
>  5. ./mktbl.pl  -S SHIFTJIS.TXT 
>  6. cd ../ces/
>  
>  7. ./mkdeps.pl
> ```

Comment: It seems I need to handle more in the scenario when a string is mixed with English and Japanese

Comment: with CES: table_pcs I could get English and Japanese working.